# How do you save outline toggles between restarts of VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Does anyone know a trick in Visual Studio 2008 to make it remember the outline toggles you have in place on aspx files between restarts? (the little plus or minus symbol on the left for code blocks)

In the code behind cs file it remembers the toggle on the #region tags... hoping for something like that I can do on the aspx HTML side.

So far I am forced to either re-close them when I open it, or do a Edit -> Outlining -> Toggle all Outlining to close them all when opening.  Nothing happy in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm frustrated by this shortcoming as well, so I submitted [feedback on Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=467059).  If this issue bothers you to, please rate it on MS Connect.

Answer (score 2):

I turn those suckers off. That way, the state is always the same, I see all the code, and it reminds me that I have to clean it up.

However, to answer your question, I don't think there is active way to control that after you close the file.